# Some Error when import the FastText model

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, gensim

My previous code run without problem 2 days ago. Today, when I rerun the program

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText
```

, it gives me following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-620c65fa4338> in <module>
     15 
     16 #nlp package
---> 17 from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText
     18 #import fasttext
     19 from tqdm import tqdm

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py in <module>
      9 import logging
     10 
---> 11 from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
     12 
     13 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/corpora/__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # bring corpus classes directly into package namespace, to save some typing
----> 6 from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
      7 
      8 from .mmcorpus import MmCorpus  # noqa:F401

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py in <module>
     12 import numpy
     13 
---> 14 from gensim import interfaces, utils
     15 
     16 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/interfaces.py in <module>
     17 import logging
     18 
---> 19 from gensim import utils, matutils
     20 
     21 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py in <module>
   1028 try:
   1029     # try to load fast, cythonized code if possible
-> 1030     from gensim._matutils import logsumexp, mean_absolute_difference, dirichlet_expectation
   1031 
   1032 except ImportError:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/_matutils.pyx in init gensim._matutils()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

What should I do to make the code can run successful, please?

Answer (score 0):

Something has likely changed in your Python environment since when it last ran without error.

An error about potential binary incompatibilities often means installed libraries don't match the expectations of the current Python interpreter.

Might the Python interpreter, or any involved libraries, have been updated or otherwise replaced recently?

Are you sure you are activating & using the same Python environment as when it worked?

How are you causing the `import` line-of-code to be run?

It appears you are using a `conda`-managed Python installation  & environment.

You may want to create a fresh environment from scratch, & re-install all required packages (including Gensim) into it, to be sure the properly-matched compiled libraries are in place.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to start everything from the scratch.